# Proc oracle issue - call executed but no insertion ( ORACLE / PLSQL )

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying to make a procedure in oracle with PL/SQL. This proc has to call a function with a value return and then update a colown with this value. My proc is executing normaly but the insertion to try the proc are not working. Im a bit lost.

The proc :

```
PROCEDURE depot_enrichment(babas number) IS
-- Curseur
CURSOR V_CURS_CDIS_CTC IS SELECT DISTINCT CD_REGATE,
                                 OPT_SITE_DEPOT,
                                 TYP_PARUTION_DECLA,
                                 NUM_PUBLICATION_DECLA,
                                 CD_POSTAL,
                                 ID_LIB_PREP 
                         FROM DEPOT_IMPORT 
                         WHERE OPT_SITE_DEPOT = 81001210 OR OPT_SITE_DEPOT = 81001211;
-- Variables proc
p_opt_site varchar2(40); -- DepotCDIS/DepotCTC
-- Variables parameters function
v_CodeSiteDepot VARCHAR2(40);   ----- 531980    
v_OptionSiteDepot VARCHAR2(40); ----  81001210/81001211
v_TypeParution VARCHAR2(40);   ----   N1, N2, N3 ..........
v_NoPublication VARCHAR2(40);----    1222K82523
v_codePostal VARCHAR2(40); -----     55000
v_NiveauPrepa VARCHAR2(40); ----      50001,50002,5003
-- Libelle parameters function    
v_LibOptionSiteDepot VARCHAR2(40); ----  DepotCDIS/DepotCTC
v_LibTypeParution VARCHAR2(40); ---- NUM , FCS ..........
v_LibNiveauPrepa VARCHAR2(40); ----      ATTF, LATD, LDCP, LDQL ou PEM
BEGIN  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- SUB-PROC OPT SIT DEPOT ENRICHIMENT - ENR4 :détermination de OptionSiteDepot pour les produits Presse
-- Enrichment of the opt_site_depot - JIRA : 1003
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- option DepotCDIS / CTC 
OPEN V_CURS_CDIS_CTC;
LOOP 
  fetch V_CURS_CDIS_CTC into v_CodeSiteDepot,v_OptionSiteDepot,v_TypeParution,v_NoPublication,v_codePostal,v_NiveauPrepa;
  EXIT WHEN V_CURS_CDIS_CTC%notfound;

    Insert into babas values ('Parametres : ' || v_CodeSiteDepot || ' / ' || v_OptionSiteDepot || ' / ' || v_TypeParution || ' / ' || v_NoPublication || ' / ' || v_codePostal || ' / ' || v_NiveauPrepa);

    -- GET LIBELLE FROM PARAMETERS VARIABLES
    SELECT LIB.LIB_LIBELLE INTO v_LibOptionSiteDepot FROM LIBELLE LIB WHERE typ_libelle = 'OSD' and id_libelle = v_CodeSiteDepot;
    SELECT TYP.LIB_PARUTION INTO v_LibTypeParution FROM TYPE_PARUTION TYP WHERE id_type_parution = v_TypeParution;
    SELECT LIB.VAL_LIBELLE INTO v_LibNiveauPrepa FROM LIBELLE LIB WHERE typ_libelle = 'PEC' and id_libelle = v_NiveauPrepa;

    Insert into babas values ('Parametres libelles: ' || v_CodeSiteDepot || ' / ' || v_LibOptionSiteDepot || ' / ' || v_LibTypeParution || ' / ' || v_NoPublication || ' / ' || v_codePostal || ' / ' || v_LibNiveauPrepa);
  -- CALL FUNCTION
    p_opt_site := return_option_CDIS_CTC(v_CodeSiteDepot,v_LibOptionSiteDepot,v_LibTypeParution,v_NoPublication,v_codePostal,v_LibNiveauPrepa);
    Insert into babas values ('option site dépot : ' || p_opt_site);
  -- UPDATE ROWS
  UPDATE DEPOT_IMPORT SET OPT_SITE_DEPOT = p_opt_site;  
END LOOP;
CLOSE V_CURS_CDIS_CTC;  

END depot_enrichment;
```

When i call the proc :

[image]

what is inserted in babas table :

[image]

I've the impression the modification code into libelle ( the 3 select ) is not working, i try the query alone and it returns me the right value. I dont understand, if you have any documentions or advises, will be really cool :)

Comment: does this procedure have insert into babas return_option_CDIS_CTC

Answer (score 0):

`Commit` is necessary to be placed at the end of the procedure to reflect the changes.

```
....
....
 UPDATE DEPOT_IMPORT SET OPT_SITE_DEPOT = p_opt_site;  
END LOOP;
COMMIT; -- this is needed here
CLOSE V_CURS_CDIS_CTC;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 `insert into babas` statements within the loop, but - according to output you get, only the first one:

```
Insert into babas values ('Parametres : ' ...
```

does its job. Where are other two?

---

When calling the procedure, you specified owner name:

```
call sagapec_import.depot_enrichment(0);
     --------------
     this
```

Is the `babas` table owned by that user? Are you connected as `sagapec_import`? Because, maybe you're executing procedure in one schema and check the result in another.

---

Finally, this:

```
UPDATE DEPOT_IMPORT SET OPT_SITE_DEPOT = p_opt_site;
```

doesn't contain `WHERE` clause which means that you'll every time update all rows in that table. Is that correct?